# Facebook post UI after approval for v2

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

Recently a change is observed in the Post UI for images. It shows caption and link name on the image besides showing the same in the RHS of the image. Post snippet is attached. I tried using large image but even then post shows caption on the image itself. How can I avoid showing caption and other stuff on the image? 
I am using following metatags:

```
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="30" />
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="600" />
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="${appId}"/>
```

See attached snippets.

[image: image shows caption]

Comment: Have you re-scraped the URL in the [OpenGraph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) after making your changes?

Comment: Yes, I did and it worked, Sorry for the late answer.